# The host machine doesn't recognize BeagleBone device with SD card inserted

Tags: ubuntu, boot, embedded, macos, beagleboneblack

I am trying to boot BeagleBone Black (BBB) off the SD card that contains boot images and rootfs files, but when I have it inserted into the BBB, I don't see any device being detected by the host machine (Mac), whereas when I took the SD card out, I saw the device appear.

Though I did add the BBB device as USB in a VirtualBox that I was using before but decided to only use the host. I quit VirtualBox now so that should't be the cause of the issue

Is there any way the files aren't properly being read by the BBB resulting in device not being detected? What could be a logical reasoning?

For reference:
[BOOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxRbO.png)
[ROOTFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyUUC.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are actually quite many things that can go wrong with this.

As you don't say that you press S2 while powering up, it is most likely using the eMMC stored U-Boot and that might not be compatible with what is on your SD card.

I've written a quite detailed Answer about this topic a while ago:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51829891/2648865

My main suggestion though is: Get a UART adapter, as then it will be quite obvious or at least easier to see what goes wrong.

Comment: I don't see anything coming up in the UART port either

Comment: If you boot from eMMC, do you see U-Boot output?

Comment: I only have an SD card

Comment: eMMC is the soldered on storage, if you remove the SD card and don't press S2 and power up. That's what gets booted. Do you see U-Boot output from that?

Comment: No. Just to make sure, I have connected the usb-ttl as shown here: https://www.dummies.com/computers/beaglebone/how-to-connect-the-beaglebone-black-via-serial-over-usb/
and then I'm using minicom to access the serial port

Comment: actually...I'm seeing boot logs now. The OS is being loaded off eMMC? now how do I get it to boot off the SD card?

Comment: with SD card inserted, I don't see this specific serial port coming up which I used in case of no SD card to access linux shell. The issue is with the image that's in the SD card?

Comment: The serial port should always be there if you use a TTL adapter. Are you sure you have a TTL adapter? What Chip does it use (check the driver details)? The emulated USB-serial over the USB port of the beaglebone is **not** what I'm talking about.

Comment: I double checked. There are two serial ports that show up without an SD card. One is from the USB-TTL cable that's connected to UART pins on the board, and the other is `tty.usbmodem<some-numbers>` and i'm not certain what refers to exactly, but I should be accessing the former one to access the UART

Comment: so if the usb-ttl gets detected without sd card, it should work with sd card too